# Why is my onclick not linking to my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, html, onclick

I am in the middle of creating a webpage that links to a web service to display a list of store names. I have created a link to the web service, and I have created an onclick function called GetOrders. I have put it in both my HTML5 page and my JavaScript page and I have linked them together. When I attempt to run the application, however, nothing happens. I have used the debugger tool on internet explorer to follow my code, but it only shows that the button has been clicked, and nothing else. none of the JavaScript code that I have is being executed. The only part of my JavaScript code that is working is my menu choice function. Can you please help me find out why my GetOrders function is not being executed?

My HTML5 Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Adam Zeidan Assignment 4</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/Assignment4.css" />
    <script src="js/Assignment4.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <section id="title">
     <h1>Module 4 Demonstration</h1>
        <hr>
        <select onchange="MenuChoice()" id="menu">
           <option>Please select an option</option>
           <option>Store List</option>
           <option>Order History</option>
        </select>
      <hr>
    </section>
    <section id="section1" class="section1">
     <h2>This is section one!</h2>
        <button onclick="GetOrders()" id="orders">Display Store List</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label id="storelistdisplay">The store list will be displayed here.    </label>
    </section>
    <section id="section2" class="section2">
     <h2>This is section two!</h2>
    </section>



</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript Page:

```
function MenuChoice()
{
    {
     if (document.getElementById("menu").value == "Store List")
    {
     document.getElementById("section1").style.visibility = "visible";
     document.getElementById("section2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
     else if (document.getElementById("menu").value == "Order History")
    {
     document.getElementById("section1").style.visibility = "hidden";
     document.getElementById("section2").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
     else
    {
     document.getElementById("section1").style.visibility = "hidden";
     document.getElementById("section2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}

function GetOrders()
    {
        var objRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Create AJAX request object

        //Create URL and Query string
        var url = "http://bus-    pluto.ad.uab.edu/jsonwebservice/service1.svc/getAllStores/";
        url += document.getElementById("custid").value;

        //Checks that the object has returned data
        objRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (objRequest.readyState == 4 && objRequest.status == 200)
                {
                    var output = JSON.parse(objRequest.responseText);
                    GenerateOutput(output);
                }
            }
        //initiate server request
        objRequest.open("GET", url, true);
        objRequest.send();
    }
}
function GenerateOutput (result)
{
    var count = 0;
    var displaytext = "";

    //This loop will extract data from the data recieved from the server
    for (count = 0; count < result.GetAllStoresResult.Length; count++)
    {
        displaytext = result.GetAllStoresResult[count].StoreID + ", " +     result.GetAllStoresResult[count].StoreName + ", " +     result.GetAllStoresResult[count].StoreCity + "<br>";
    }

    document.getElementById("storelistdisplay").innerHTML = displaytext;
}
```

Comment: There's a big space in your URL. Are you getting any 404 errors?

Comment: You have an extra `{` in your `MenuChoice()` function, which is probably a syntax error and killing the entire js page.

Comment: I do not have a big space in my url code. It must have been an error when i was copying my code here. and i am not getting an 404 errors, and i have deleted the extra { that i had, but it killed my entire js page.

Answer (score 0):

Like Marc B commented above, it's probably the misplaced `{` that's causing your problem.  In `MenuChoice()` the first if statement has it's opening curly bracket before, not after the if clause.

Answer (score 0):

Small typo error on your JS file, extra "}" in GetOrders funtion. I corrected it. Use below code.

```
function GetOrders()
    {
        var objRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Create AJAX request object

        //Create URL and Query string
        var url = "http://bus-    pluto.ad.uab.edu/jsonwebservice/service1.svc/getAllStores/";
        url += document.getElementById("custid").value;

        //Checks that the object has returned data
        objRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (objRequest.readyState == 4 && objRequest.status == 200)
                {
                    var output = JSON.parse(objRequest.responseText);
                    GenerateOutput(output);
                }
            }
        //initiate server request
        objRequest.open("GET", url, true);
        objRequest.send();
    }
```